# Singletone Object on Client side in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I want Singletone Object on **`Client side`** in **`GWT`**.

I want one Singletone `Map(String, Map(String, Object) )`  ChangeMap(i.e., Single object of that ChangeMap for whole application) that will store changes made by any user.

every user can get all changes made by any user.

For example,There are two users ABC and XYZ who have logged in to the GWT App.

Now user ABC has add two Cities and deleted 1 country via Application.

And user XYZ has added two new users and has updated one new role.

Then in that ChangeMap, Values shoud be :

changeMap

```
{ {"ABC",{"added",City1} }, 
  {"ABC",{"added",City2} } , 
  {"ABC",{"deleted",country1} }, 
  {"XYZ",{"added",User1} }, 
  {"XYZ",{"added",User2} }, 
  {"XYZ",{"updated",Role1} }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,GWT plays on `client` side without sending any `requests` to `server` other users wont get those `effects`.

Remember that singleton object must be in the servletVContext not even ib the `session` so that every user can access it.

When some one done an event by making a server call(`RPC`) update that map  and send the changes to all other users through some  [**event service**](https://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/).

Here is the [code examples](https://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/wiki/CodeExamples) of events which i am talking about.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But there should be some other way to do that. I am using spring for Controller. Do you have idea for that?

Comment: May be server push helps you out.No idea is there any better alternatives.